# Google sitemap plugin generating incorrect URL

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

I am working on WordPress website. For site map purpose i had uploaded google sitemap plugin. But this plugin generating all wrong urls. Then I deactivated  this plugin installed some other plugins like yoast, all in one seo etc... . All plugins generating wrong sitemap.

Url looks like :

```
http://example.com /8/L-sB6mKmQJNwBW/-ysLA/08T9jrAY.eztvv
http://example.com /u-liK3ZKxwaenzP_hh-tO_5cV20qtL.smu
```

How to resolve this problem. please help

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Yoast common sitemap errors: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/xml-sitemap-errors/

Comment: I checked this. But didn't find solution. thank you